# Javascript - Mail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

I want to send an email in a text-area to many other users. In the text-area, named content, if I typed "user" surrounded by stars, I want to have them filled in with each email's username (the text before the "@"). That would yield many different with each username in each email. Then when I hit a button, I want to have all the emails sent to each corresponding user. This is my mail function so far:

```
function mail(){
    var options = document.getElementById('users').options
    var emails = []
    for(var i = 2; i < options.length; i++){
        emails.push(options[i].innerHTML)
    }   
}
```

How do I do this? Thanks!!!

Comment: You can't send email directly from JavaScript. You need to use a server-side script to do it.

Comment: You need to use PHP or another server-side scripting language. See my answer below on how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to send an email using JavaScript, but you can do it with PHP. Here, the variable `options` you have above has been placed in a form and sent to the PHP page via POST, with the `name="options"` in the `input` attribute:

```
<?php
    $options = $_POST['options'];
    $to = "person@example.com";
    $subject = "Random Life";
    $body = "Lorem ipsum dolor. $options";

    mail ($to,$subject,$body);

 ?>
```

This will send an email to `person@example.com`, with the subject `Random Life`, and the content `Lorem ipsum dolor [options]`, where `options` is the value passed by the form.

But in finality, no, it is not possible to send an email using JavaScript ***currently***. It may be possible in future years, but currently not available.