# Sending email with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, email

How can I have user on my site send an email to someone using their own email directly from the website without opening email application?

I have an app where they create a PDF and at the end they need to email it to someone from their email by entering their email and clicking a button. Is there any way to do that?

Sorry if this is obvious, but I've done a lot of looking around and can't seem to find a relevant answer. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You'd need a server-side language for that - look at Node.js and PHP

Comment: You will likely need some sort of server to handle that -- basically, a form would be submitted on the front end, the PDF would be sent to the server, and emailed to the recipient from there. There is always the option of http://www.emailjs.com/ or something similar, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same PHP as my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086459/javascript-mail/52089557#52089557):

```
$to = "person@example.com";
$subject = "Foo and Bar";
$body = "Lorem ipsum dolor";

mail ($to,$subject,$body);
```

The above is a very basic mail system. It can be integrated with a form for more options, and accessibility from a HTML page.

More information about `mail()` can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).